# How to make background images load faster

Tags: wordpress, background-image, core-web-vitals

Most of my WordPress websites have a background image in the top fold. These images are the Largest Contentful Paint Element on the page and usually they get loaded last. Somewhere I read that 'Background images are last in line to be grabbed when a page is loaded'. Is it true?
Is it a good idea to use a place holder or image in the place of the background image and then change it later so that the LCP gets loaded quickly like below.

```
<div class="header-img"><img style="display: none;" src="images/header-img.jpg" alt=""></div>

.header-img {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-size: cover;
background-image: url(images/header-img.jpg);
```

}

[Source](https://justmarkup.com/articles/2015-02-02-prioritize-loading-of-background-images/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use a placeholder image to prioritize your background images in situations like this, you want to use `<link rel="preload">`. That will tell the browser to start downloading the image as soon as possible.

Try adding the following code to the `<head>` of your page, and then use your background image as normal. It should load much faster:

```html
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="images/header-img.jpg">
```

You can read more about this technique here:

- [Preload critical assets to improve loading speed](https://web.dev/preload-critical-assets/)
- [Preloading responsive images](https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/)

Comment: Thank you so much Philip but usually I have a background image in the top fold and that is the LCP element of the page and that loads last.  I thought it loads last because the background images load last on the web page.

Comment: It probably loads late because the CSS file referencing the image needs to load first, so the browser doesn't know it has to start loading the background image until after it finishes loading and parsing the CSS file. But with `<link rel=preload>` the browser can start loading the image right away (even before loading the CSS file).

Comment: Thanks a ton for your inputs @PhilipWalton